# WebKitのファイルオープン（アップロード）パネルのカスタマイズ

Tags: macos, swiftui, webkit

`SwiftUI`で`WKWebView`を表示し、任意のページを表示することは出来ました。しかし、ページ内の「（アップロード）ファイルを選択」をクリックすると、

- ファイルダイアログが、WebViewの中心ではなく、スクリーンの中心に表示されます
- 確定ボタンが`Safari`ではUploadと表示されますが、Openと表示されます

この２点を修正するには、コードをどの様に修正したら良いのでしょうか？ご存じの方、お教え下さい。
ファイルダイアログの位置については、`frame: WKFrameInfo`をいじれば良いような気がしますがまだ暗中模索状態です。

`WKUIDelegate`の`open`デリゲートは以下のように書いています

```swift
public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runOpenPanelWith parameters: WKOpenPanelParameters, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping ([URL]?) -> Void) {
    let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
    openPanel.canChooseFiles = true
    openPanel.begin { (result) in
        if result == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK {
            if let url = openPanel.url {
                completionHandler([url])
            }
        } else if result == NSApplication.ModalResponse.cancel {
            completionHandler(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

- 追記、ボタンをUploadにすることは、`openPanel = NSOpenPanel()`でインスタンスを生成した後、`openPanel.prompt = "Upload"`で出来ました。残る問題はダイアログの位置の調整だけになりました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OpenPanel`を`.begin`で使うのではなく、`.beginSheetModal`で使う事で解決しました。修正したコードは以下のようになります。

```swift
public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runOpenPanelWith parameters: WKOpenPanelParameters, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping ([URL]?) -> Void) {
    func handleResult(_ result: NSApplication.ModalResponse) {
        if result == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK, let url = openPanel.url {
            completionHandler([url])
        } else {
            completionHandler(nil)
        }
    }
    
    let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
    openPanel.prompt = String(localized: "Upload")
    openPanel.message = String(localized: "title")
    openPanel.canChooseFiles = true
    if let window = webView.window {
        openPanel.beginSheetModal(for: window, completionHandler: handleResult)
    } else { // web view is somehow not in a window? Fall back to begin
        openPanel.begin(completionHandler: handleResult)
    }
}
```